# Multipanel with raster (spplot) and scatter plot in R

Tags: raster, r, plot

I have one raster and one scatter plot that I want to put together in a single multipanel plot. However, the `par(mfrow=c())` that usually works to put together different normal plots, doesn't work when I am trying to visualize a raster with the `sp::spplot` function. I am looking for a way to put both types of plots together in a single figure

This IS an example code of what I have been trying to do, but it ends with the plot in separate figures.

```
library(sp)

r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
x <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
y <- rnorm(100, 1, 5)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
spplot(r)
plot(x, y)
```